# Bitcoin-cli keeps crashing around block 810180 and will always restart at block 809941

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, debugging

So I'm downloading and syncing the blockchain using bitcoin core. Whenever it teaches block 810810, the terminal will just close by itself and then I restart the node, it will start syncing from block 809940. The debug.log file doesn't show any errors, it just stops at that point. This has happened about 5 times in a row now. The laptop I'm running it on has 8gb of ram and a terabyte of harddrive space. I checked for any hardware failures but the harddrive passes all checks. For what it's worth, my bitcoin.conf file looks like:

`prune=5000`

That's it.

The debug log's output when I run it with just the -daemon flag is:

```
2023-10-07T00:29:39Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000000f560e0495f776189c1ba681c8fe4068ecd33d16584d6 height=810181 version=0x302a0000 log2_work=94.450324 tx=902025944 date='2023-10-01T18:26:02Z' progress=0.998156 cache=270.2MiB(1774949txo)

2023-10-07T00:29:39Z New outbound peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=810972, peer=268 (outbound-full-relay)

2023-10-07T00:29:51Z UpdateTip: new best=00000000000000000001efe8dc90d79e52d1de934ecffc03572d847ea8fc7296 height=810182 version=0x241c2000 log2_work=94.450337 tx=902028692 date='2023-10-01T18:33:00Z' progress=0.998158 cache=271.1MiB(1781754txo)

2023-10-07T00:29:58Z UpdateTip: new best=000000000000000000040caf3f438bb15731f6dc0f5ce1eaa6cd2ee8213d72dd height=810183 version=0x22c88000 log2_work=94.450350 tx=902031063 date='2023-10-01T18:35:09Z' progress=0.998158 cache=271.6MiB(1786104txo)
```

The last few lines of the debug file when running it with the flags -nodaemon and -debug are:

```
2023-10-07T06:30:41Z [net] received block 00000000000000000000f560e0495f776189c1ba681c8fe4068ecd33d16584d6 peer=56
2023-10-07T06:30:41Z [net] Added connection peer=63
2023-10-07T06:30:41Z [validation] Pre-allocating up to position 0x5000000 in blk03857.dat
2023-10-07T06:30:41Z [bench] FlushStateToDisk: find files to prune started
2023-10-07T06:30:51Z [rand] Feeding 18303 bytes of dynamic environment data into RNG
```

Any idea what could be going on? It's taken me 10 days to get to this point. I really hope I can continue from here.

Comment: Which version of Bitcoin core are you using?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick According to the debug log I am using bitcoin core version v25.0rc2

Comment: When you run it in the terminal, there aren't any additional messages, perhaps something with the word "assert" or "assertion"?

Comment: @AndrewChow Nope, nothing at all. The terminal window will just close.

Comment: @AndrewChow I deleted the peers.dat file then restarted the node and it's gotten past the "problem block". There was nothing in the debug file to suggest that that file was a problem, but for some reason it seems to have done the trick; at least so far. I don't want to celebrate too early.

Comment: @AndrewChow I'm having an issue now where the node will be fully synced, then the terminal will just close by itself. When I restart the node, it will start a couple hundred blocks before the point at which it closed. Again, there's nothing in the debug log that shows an error (or assert/assertion) or anything like that. I know it's not much to go on, but any idea why this could be happening?

Edit: I'm running this on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and there are no other programs running while the node is running. This laptop is dedicated entirely to running this node.